# Replace a computed getter/setter with mapState and mapMutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, computed-properties

So, I am syncing a computed value to a component and setting it with a computed setter when it syncs back from the component.

My question is: Is it possible to replace a computed getter/setter with mapState and mapMutations or how would one achieve this in a more compact way?

```js
<template>
    <SomeComponent :value.sync="globalSuccess"></SomeComponent>
</template>
export default {
    //...
    computed: {
        globalSuccess: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.globalSuccess;
            },
            set(val) {
                this.$store.commit("globalSuccess", val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried replacing it like this:

```js
export default {
    //...
    computed: {
        ...mapState(["globalSuccess"]),
        ...mapMutations(["globalSuccess"]),
    }
}
```

But unfortunately `mapMutations(["globalSuccess"])` maps `this.globalSuccess(value)` to `this.$store.commit('globalSuccess', value)` according to the [documentation of vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components).

But since my computed value gets set with `globalSuccess = true` internally through `:value.sync` in the template and not `this.globalSuccess(true)`, `globalSuccess` will never be set to `true`.

Any idea how this could be possible? Or am I stuck using computed values with getter and setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just found out about this vuex module https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields which I installed as described on there:

```js
// store.js
import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields';
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    getters: {
        getField,
        //...
    },
    mutations: {
        updateField,
        //...
    },
});
```

And then I made use of `mapFields` function:

```js
// App.vue
export default {
    //...
    computed: {
        ...mapFields(["globalSuccess"]),
    }
}
```

Which apparently dynamically maps to a computed setter and getter exactly as I wanted it:

```js
export default {
    //...
    computed: {
        globalSuccess: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.globalSuccess;
            },
            set(val) {
                this.$store.commit("globalSuccess", val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a syntax I use:

```js
export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    globalSuccess: {
      ...mapState({ get: 'globalSuccess' }),
      ...mapMutations({ set: 'globalSuccess' }),
    },
  },
}
```

No additional dependencies needed. If you use it a lot, I suppose you could create a helper for it, but it is pretty neat as it is.